# How to join on more three tables in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I would like to join more than three tables in Rails 3.

My code is

```
class offer < ActiveRecord::Base 

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :usercomments, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :comments, :through => :usercomments, :dependent => :destroy

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :usercomments, :dependent =>:destroy
  has_many :comments,:through => :usercomments, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :offers, :dependent => :destroy

end 

class Usercomment < ActiveRecord::Base
  
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :comment
  belongs_to :offer

end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  
  has_one :usercomment, :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :offer, :through => :usercomments
  has_one :user, :through => :usercomments

end
```

My schema is:

```
create_table "offers", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "step_id"  
  t.integer  "user_id"  
  t.date     "offerdate"  
end

create_table "users", :force => true do |t|  
  t.string   "firstname",            :limit => 100, :default => ""  
  t.string   "lastname",             :limit => 100, :default => ""  
  t.string   "email",                :limit => 100  
end

create_table "usercomments", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "airoffer_id"
  t.integer  "comment_id"
  t.boolean  "shared"
end 

create_table "comments", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "comment" 
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

and index.html.erb is:

```
 <% airoffers.each do |airoffer| %>

???

 <% end %>
```

In my html.erb page I would like to find a comment for an offer (`offer_id`) and an user (`user_id`).

Comment: Please can you indent your code and include an example of what you need in your view.

Comment: Excuse me Mark for my bad practice, i indent my code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like what you want is:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :comments
   has_many :offers
end

class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :comments
   belongs_to :user
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :offer
end
```

If you want all the Comments that belong to a specific User and a specific Offer, just do `Comment.where(:user_id => # :offer_id => #)` and pass in the User and Offer you want.

Does this help?

Comment: Yes Adam, it's true. My analyze is wrong. The user id must be in the comment model, with the offer id i think. Thank you help.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you an array of comments for User#123 en Offer#456

```
UserComment.find(:all, :conditions => {
  :user_id  => 123,
  :offer_id => 456
}).collect(&:comment)
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but there are no solution to use associate model properties of rails ?

Comment: Yes, there probably are, but in this example you don't have to touch the `users` table at all. All other solution add `users` to the join, which will slow down your query. This may seem insignificant now but when the size of your data grows and the number of queries goes up, you'll thank me.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i chose this solution

my code

```
class offer < ActiveRecord::Base 

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy, :order => "updated_at DESC"

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :comments,:dependent => :destroy
  has_many :offers, :dependent => :destroy

end 

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  
  has_one :user, :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :airoffer, :dependent => :destroy

end
```

schema

```
create_table "offers", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"  
  t.date     "offerdate"  
end

create_table "users", :force => true do |t|  
  t.string   "firstname",            :limit => 100, :default => ""  
  t.string   "lastname",             :limit => 100, :default => ""  
  t.string   "email",                :limit => 100  
end

create_table "comments", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "offer_id"  
  t.string   "comment" 
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

in offer_controller.rb

```
@offers = User.find(current_user.id).offers.includes(:comments)
```

and in my index.html.erb

```
<% @offers.each do |airoffer| %>
  <% airoffer.comments[0].comment %>
<% end %>
```

I know, it's not the better solution, but in the first time i will use it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use it this way:

```
Comment.find( 
  :all, 
  :conditions => {
    :user_id  => 123,
    :offer_id => 456
  },
  :join => :usercomment
)
```

OR:

```
Comment.find( 
  :all, 
  :conditions => [
    "usercomments.user_id = ? AND usercomments.offer_id = ?",
    123,
    456
  ],
  :join => :usercomment
)
```

Rails have a lot of beautiful ways to write queries.